# How Can I Show Data in One Line With SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I ordered the products "Cookie" and "Coffee" after adding the basket. Then this is my `Order` table:

[image: This is my order table after I ordered 2 products:]

Then I wrote a code as below:

```
SELECT Order.OrderDate
    , User.NAME
    , User.Surname
    , User.Phone
    , User.Adress
    , Product.ProductName
    , Order.Price
    , Order.Piece
    , Cargo.CargoPrice 
FROM Order 
INNER JOIN User ON Order.UserID = User.UserID 
INNER JOIN Product ON Order.ProductID = Product.ProductID 
INNER JOIN Cargo ON Order.CargoID = Cargo.CargoID 
WHERE Order.OrderDate = '2018-02-05 17:30:13.000' 
AND Order.UserID = '1'
```

So the output is as follows:

[image: This is my output after the SQL code:]

So the total value of my order must be 90 + 80 + 7 = 177 and I want to show these values in one line: `user name`, `user surname`, `total price`, `product date`.

Comment: what if the user places 7 orders on the same date... i can't work out if you want those rows side by side or grouped/totalled.. please clarify

Comment: On a side note: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154251/1822

Comment: You want it on one line, okay, what information do ***you*** want that one line to contain?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name of all the comments at that thread yours made me nearly spit out my coffee I was laughing so hard. "Do you prefix all your classes in your programming language (Java, C++, Scala, ....) with Class?"

Comment: @SeanLange: well, that **is** the equivalent to prefixing a table with `tbl_`, isn't it ;)

Comment: No I just wrote it here like this because normally I am using the language of my own country in my database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it absolutely is. I love that analogy!!!

Comment: I just want to show the different products that a user adds to the basket in a single row. @Tanner

Comment: You need to help us understand what you want here. We see a couple of rows of data but no idea what you expect as output. I have to say that from what is posted this looks like it should be two tables, not one. Here is a great place to get some idea of what want to see from you. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Okey I'll try to explain. My English is not good but I'll try. A user added a basket of product x and y. Then ordered. The products that this user has given in the order table were recorded in different rows. When I approve this order in the management panel I want it to appear as one line instead of 2 lines. Because I need to show the total price and the transportation fee in a single line.

Comment: Would not it be unreasonable to write the total price and the carriage price on both lines? As a result, a single order with these 2 different products. @SeanLange

Comment: @Shadouspan Please show sample output based on your example

Comment: What you are describing is exactly why you want two tables. One for the OrderHeader (customer info, shipping, tax etc) and another for OrderDetails (each product, quantity etc.). But the real issue with your question remains....what do you want to display? Give us some data instead of trying to explain it in a language you are not comfortable with (but to be honest your English is just fine from what I can tell).

Comment: I've edit my question again. Would you check? @SeanLange

Comment: You are long on needing help and extremely short on providing details. Did you see the link I posted 45 minutes ago? I am totally guessing here because you refuse to make this easy, try looking into SUM perhaps?

Comment: Isn't the value of the order (cookie = 40*2) + (coffee = 30*3) + (cargo = 7*7) = 184?

Comment: Yes I typed wrong. 80 + 90 + 7 = 177. We take the cargo price 1 time because the two products are in one order. @Cool_Br33ze

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for your problem

```
SELECT 
      User.NAME
    , User.Surname
    , TotalPrice = SUM((Order.Price * Order.Piece) + MIN(Cargo.CargoPrice) )
    , Order.OrderDate
FROM Order 
INNER JOIN User ON Order.UserID = User.UserID 
INNER JOIN Product ON Order.ProductID = Product.ProductID 
INNER JOIN Cargo ON Order.CargoID = Cargo.CargoID 
WHERE Order.OrderDate = '2018-02-05 17:30:13.000' 
AND Order.UserID = '1'
GROUP BY
      User.NAME
    , User.Surname
    , Order.OrderDate
```